# Why does this WebP Support function return random results each time it's run?

Tags: javascript, function, webp

I'm trying to create a piece of code that determines if the browser supports WebP images or not to then determine if it loads JPEG's or WebP's. It seems to randomly return true and false on each browser refresh.

```
function supportsWebP() {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "/img/test-img.png";

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = img.naturalWidth; // or 'width' if you want a special/scaled size
    canvas.height = img.naturalHeight; // or 'height' if you want a special/scaled size

    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/webp');
    if (data.startsWith("data:image/webp")) { // Will start with "data:image/png" if unsupported
        console.info("WebP is supported by your browser.");
        return true;
    }

    console.warn("WebP is NOT supported by your browser. Consider upgrading to Chrome/updating your browser version");
    return false;
}
```

When it is first run, it returns `false` but if I run it a while afterwards, it returns true. Why is this?

(I am using Chrome Canary on the latest build and have also tried it on the latest Google Chrome release)

EDIT: `test-img.png` is a 1px x 1px image solely consisting of a 100% black (`#000000`) pixel.

Comment: What happens if you loop over the drawImage() function twice in the function, and check the data the second time? Will that always return true in that case? Perhaps there is something nondeterministic about calling toDataURL with webp images? Seems strange that you would need to do that, it indeed seems you need to resort to a hack to get it consistent.

Comment: FYI, `Firefox` does **not** support webp

Comment: @SamuelCook Indeed they dont

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes some time to apply `src` to the `image`, so use `onload` listener:

```js
function supportsWebP() {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJChQODwwQFxQYGBcUFhYaHSUfGhsjHBYWICwgIyYnKSopGR8tMC0oMCUoKSj/2wBDAQcHBwoIChMKChMoGhYaKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCj/wAARCAABAAEDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAFQABAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAf/xAAUEAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/8QAFQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgT/xAAUEQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwCoAEhf/9k=";
  
  img.onload = () => {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = img.naturalWidth; // or 'width' if you want a special/scaled size
    canvas.height = img.naturalHeight; // or 'height' if you want a special/scaled size

    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/webp');
    if (data.startsWith("data:image/webp")) { // Will start with "data:image/png" if unsupported
      console.info("WebP is supported by your browser.");
      return true;
    }

    console.warn("WebP is NOT supported by your browser. Consider upgrading to Chrome of Firefox/updating your browser version");
    return false;
  }
}


supportsWebP()
```

Comment: @DavidWheatley, happy to help!